# Woocommerce discount by user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

EDIT: As you see I'm new here. So sorry for giving you a headache
This is the problem at the moment:
The code is working now! But maybe it has something to do with taxes when the product price on shop page differs from cart and checkout page.

Just to be clear I've inserted the price with no VAT included and on shop page the VAT is not included. But on cart page the VAT is calculated.

Summary:

- Product price is: 10 €
- With 22% discount it's 7.80 €
- With 24% VAT it's: ~ 9.67 €
- But on cart and checkout page it says total: 11.16 €

[Shop page – Quick cart open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fVSG.png)

I'm currently working on a very complicated project with Wordpress + Woocommerce and I'm not so familiar with PHP and Wordpress/Woocommerce hooks. I'm trying to apply a percentage discount to products with category X. I'm running into issues like

> A non-numeric value encountered

on dashboard and the price differs from product archive page on cart/checkout page.

Here's my code on functions.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2);

function custom_price($price, $product)
{
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $price;

  if (has_role('hintaluokka-5')) {
    $price = $price * 0.95;
  } elseif (has_role('hintaluokka-12')) {
    $price = $price * 0.88;
  } elseif (has_role('hintaluokka-15')) {
    $price = $price * 0.85;
  } elseif (has_role('hintaluokka-22')) {
    if (has_term('kastikkeet', 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
      $price = $price * 0.78;
    } else {
      $price = $price * 0.9;
    }
  }
  return $price;
}

function has_role($role = '', $user_id = null)
{
  if (is_numeric($user_id))
    $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  else
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if (empty($user))
    return false;

  return in_array($role, (array) $user->roles);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $price;
    }

    if ( has_role( 'hintaluokka-5' ) ) {
        $price *= 0.95;
    } elseif ( has_role( 'hintaluokka-12' ) ) {
        $price *= 0.88;
    } elseif ( has_role( 'hintaluokka-15' ) ) {
        $price *= 0.85;
    } elseif ( has_role( 'hintaluokka-22' ) ) {
        if ( has_term( 'kastikkeet', 'product_cat', $product->ID ) ) {
            $price *= 0.78;
        } else {
            $price *= 0.9;
        }
    }

    return $price;
}

function has_role( $role = '', $user_id = null ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    } else {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    }

    if ( empty( $user ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return in_array( $role, $user->roles, true );
}
```

I don't see a huge problem here. There is just one hook which is no longer used (deprecated).

Post the error message in case this don't helps.

Comment: Thanks, apparently there was somekind of magical sh*t happening on one product which broke it all. Which is now fixed. But I'm still getting a different price on shop page and cart/checkout page. I don't know if it has something to do with taxes. But I've configured taxes not to show not on shop page neither on cart but on order summary it shows the total including taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
$price = $price * 0.95;
```

What happens if `$price` is `"1$"`? In that case `$price` cannot be converted into a number in order to perform the calculate the result of the quoted formula. So, in order to solve your problem, you need to identify the exact line where the error occurs (from server error logs), find out what the variable/parameter causing the error is and convert it into a numeric value.

Comment: The price comes from the hook and is typed as an int/float

Comment: The discount code is working now but it ain't working properly on cart/checkout page.

Comment: @SamuliVälimäki you will need to identify the exact line.

Comment: @Mr.Jo if we knew what the exact line throwing the error is, then I would edit this answer with further information. Up until then I will need to explain the issue itself without being sure that the row I provide as an example is the problematic row. If not, then we will need further information from the asker.

Comment: As I answered to my original question; there's no more errors! Just a different price on shop page + quick cart and on actual cart and checkout page.

Comment: @SamuliVälimäki if your problem has been solved then you should either accept one of the answers or write an answer of your own. You are saying that you have a different problem now. Then you will try to solve this new problem and if stuck, you might want to ask another question.

Comment: @LajosArpad Cheers! Thanks for guiding me!